# Randomisation after data collection

Tags: sampling

I am undertaking a cross-sectional study. I was wondering if this was a valid way to randomise data. I have collected data from an email questionnaire. There are 35-40 responses for each cohort within the study.
Can I randomise these results in this manner: randomly allocate a number to each individual's data and then randomly pick 20 numbers. Does this create bias? Is it a completely unacceptable method of randomisation?

Comment: What would be the purpose of randomizing in that manner? Randomly selecting in this manner will not make this a random sample from the overall population and it will not make the assignment to some groups (e.g. male/female, employed/unemployed) randomized, either. But perphaps you are intending something else?

Comment: respondents are from various grades of medical school (years 3-5) and then year groups after medical school (1-3).
because it's an email questionnaire sent to all students and doctors across a large region, randomising who it is sent to is unacceptable as there is no guarantee these randomised individuals will respond. my power calculation indicates i need 20 individuals in each group for statical significance; i have over 20 respondents in each group (year 3, 4, 5 med school, year 1, 2, 3 graduated). i figured randomising in this way would at least remove some selection bias?

Comment: Why would it? You will just get a random sample of the previous sample with the exact same selection biases. Survey weights might be more likely to remove selective response issues, if you know key aspects of your overall population and the sample.

Comment: so in essence, there is no benefit? i may as well analyse the whole data and accept that this is a convenience sample in my analysis

Comment: Yes, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

Randomized studies are prospective studies whereas you are describing a retrospective study. To answer your question: no.

When you randomize, you have to ask what somebody is randomized to/for. Randomization involves administering some sort of experimental condition, such as receiving an intervention, or a drug, or a survey prototype versus some appropriate form of control: no intervention, standard care, or the usual survey instrument.

There is however, some very advanced work about the relationship between retrospective studies and randomized studies in this regard. If the experimental condition is a binary 0/1 effect, and you have information on the predictors of whether a participant receives the condition or not, propensity matching achieves an analysis sample that has all the properties of a randomized cohort: balanced predictors, no lurking variables, and so on. This is as close as you can get to a "randomized retrospective study". There are a *lot* of assumptions with that method: virtually all such analyses devote significant attention to the predictors to the receipt of experimental condition: through a scientific (not statistical) approach and across several studies before justifying propensity weighting as an appropriate analysis.